# How to use pipe in command using python sub process call

Tags: python, linux, command, subprocess, call

I am trying to filter out first 3 line of `/proc/meminfo` using pipe and head command.

so basically i need to run this in Python:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | head -3
```

I am using below line in my code :

```
subprocess.call(["cat", "/proc/meminfo", "|", "head", "-3"])
```

While just using `subprocess.call(["cat", "/proc/meminfo"])` I am getting whole list but I am just interested in first 3 line.

Using above command is giving me below error:

```
cat: invalid option -- '3'
Try `cat --help' for more information.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: pipe is provided by the shell, thus you failed. You may try

    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/cat /proc/meminfo | /usr/bin/head -3"])

Comment: There's no need to create a subprocess just to read a file.  See my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

`/proc/meminfo` is just a file.  You don't need a subprocess to read it.  Simply open and read it as a file.  Here is all you need:

```
fh = open('/proc/meminfo', 'r')
lines = fh.readlines()
fh.close()

first_lines = lines[:3]
```

The `first_lines` list will contain the first three lines (including trailing newline characters).

Comment: So...a XY problem again?

Comment: or even `list(itertools.islice(open('/proc/meminfo'), 3))` -- it doesn't matter in this case but in general, if the file is large then `islice()` is much more efficient then `.readlines()` that reads *all* lines.

Answer (score 1):

To use pip you have to enable shell as  shell=True, however it's not advisable specifically because of security reason . You can do this alternative,

```
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen(('cat', '/proc/meminfo'),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('head', '-3'), stdin=ps.stdout)
print output
```

Comment: As long as you pass a static command, meaning not based on input values, it is safe to use the `shell=True` option.

Comment: Yes you are right. I generalised answer so can be helpful for others

Comment: Thanks for the response..

Answer (score 0):

The pipe is a shell syntax element. You need to run the code *in a shell* to use a pipe:

```
subprocess.call(["cat /proc/meminfo | head -3"], shell=True)
```

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes, filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~ to a user’s home directory.

Comment: Thanks ..working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Well `head` actually accepts an argument, so the pipe is not actually necessary. The following should give the expected result.

```
subprocess.call(["head", "-3", "/proc/meminfo"])
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay... This is what i was looking for without using much a code but one liner to solve my purpose... Working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

[following this document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#frequently-used-arguments)

In default, `subprocess.call` with `shell=False` will disables all shell based features including pipe. When using `shell=True`, `pipes.quote()` can be used to properly escape whitespace and shell metacharacters in strings that are going to be used to construct shell commands.

you can use this code

```py
subprocess.call("cat /proc/meminfo | head -3", shell=True)
```